# UnitsNet - How to use it in MVC?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

How to use the UnitsNet nuget package in an MVC web application ?

For example I have my object:

```
public class UnitsNetTestViewModel
{
    public int AnInput { get; set; }
    public UnitsNet.Temperature OutdoorTemperature { get; set; }
}
```

Then my view

```
@model WebApplication.Models.UnitsNetTestViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnInput)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnInput)
    <br/>

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OutdoorTemperature)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OutdoorTemperature)
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

In my controller

```
    public class UnitsNetTestController : Controller
{
    // GET: UnitNetsTest
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new Models.UnitsNetTestViewModel {OutdoorTemperature = Temperature.FromDegreesFahrenheit(80)};
        return View("~/Views/UnitsNetTest.cshtml", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Models.UnitsNetTestViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
        }
        return View("~/Views/UnitsNetTest.cshtml", model);
    }
}
```

I have tried using `EditorFor` or `TextBoxFor`.
I have also tried binding on a different part of the object:

```
model => model.OutdoorTemperature.Value
model => model.OutdoorTemperature.DegreesFahrenheit
model => model.OutdoorTemperature
```

Even when using the `EditorFor` `model.OutdoorTemperature` combination, I get the full object input fields, when I update a value, it always return as zero in the controller submit.

What Am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

Trying to understand how the UnitsNet property is working, I added a subclass to my model to see if my subclass value will be available back in the controller (even if I already know that it will work). What I have notice from that : in the watch, the Value of my `model.Other` property is `{...WebApplication.Models.SubClass}` and the type is also `...WebApplication.Models.SubClass`. But for `model.OutdoorTemperature`, the Value is `{0 K}` and the Type is `UnitsNet.Temperature`. 
Could it be a clue ?

Here is a print screen:
[image: Debugging Watch Printscreen]

Updated class:

```
public class UnitsNetTestViewModel
{
    public int AnInput { get; set; }
    public UnitsNet.Temperature OutdoorTemperature { get; set; }
    public SubClass Other { get; set; }
}

public class SubClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int MySubClassValue { get; set; }
}
```

Updated View:

```
@model WebApplication.Models.UnitsNetTestViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnInput)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnInput)
    <br />

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OutdoorTemperature)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OutdoorTemperature.Value)

    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Other)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Other.Value)

    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Other)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Other.MySubClassValue)


    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

**EDIT 2**

The `UnitsNet.Temperature` is a struct, not a class. Will probably need a custom model binder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the default binding of MVC was not working because UnitsNet are struct.

I did a custom property binder.

I use this post as a reference : http://www.stevencwilliams.com/2015/10/26/custom-property-binding-in-asp-net-mvc/

Here is the code that get my exemple working:

```
public class TemperatureModelBinder : IPropertyBinder
{
    public object BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {            
        var propertyValue = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form[propertyDescriptor.Name];
        double.TryParse(propertyValue, out var result);

        return UnitsNet.Temperature.FromDegreesFahrenheit(result);
    }
}

public interface IPropertyBinder
{
    object BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor);
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class PropertyBinderAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type BinderType { get; private set; }

    public PropertyBinderAttribute(Type binderType)
    {
        BinderType = binderType;
    }

    public IPropertyBinder GetBinder()
    {
        return (IPropertyBinder)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(BinderType);
    }
}

public class ModelBinderBase : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
        PropertyBinderAttribute attribute = propertyDescriptor.Attributes
            .OfType<PropertyBinderAttribute>()
            .SingleOrDefault();
        if (attribute == null)
        {
            base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
        }
        else
        {
            propertyDescriptor.SetValue(bindingContext.Model, attribute.GetBinder().BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor));
        }
    }
}
```

In my model, I added my binder attribute

```
    [PropertyBinder(typeof(TemperatureModelBinder))]
    public UnitsNet.Temperature OutdoorTemperature { get; set; }
```

And in Global.asax.cs, Application_Start()

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new ModelBinderBase();
```